# How to show User name after login when not present in DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my website master page there are 2 divs- div_login and div_welcome. By default login div is visible and welcome div is hidden. When user fills his/her login details then div_login gets hide and welcome div appears. I am fetching data from web-service. On welcome div I want to give first name and last name of the user, but in case if user do not have his first name and last name in Database then welcome div appears but gives error. please help.
Website link is [this][1]

Code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["myLogin"] != null && Session["Pwd"] != null)
            {
             Login_Div.Visible = false; 
             WelCome_Div.Visible = true; 
             lblFName.Text = Sessio["lblFName"].ToStrin(); 
             lblLName.Text = Session["lblLName"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                WelCome_Div.Visible = false; Login_Div.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

      [1]: https://www.starbazaarindia.com/test/index.aspx
```

Comment: I think we need some code... What have you tried?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           if (Session["myLogin"] != null && Session["Pwd"] != null)
            {
              Login_Div.Visible = false;
              WelCome_Div.Visible = true;
               
       lblFName.Text = Session["lblFName"].ToString();
              lblLName.Text = Session["lblLName"].ToString();
             }
            else
             {
               WelCome_Div.Visible = false;
               Login_Div.Visible = true;
              }
          }
            
      }

Comment: What is the error that it gives?

Comment: Can you post welcome div code? Are you using some kind of object to store user info?

Comment: If I had to guess, if either FName or LName is null, then it might throw an error when trying to get the Session variable associated with those.  Without seeing code, or the error message, it's hard to say.

Comment: I got the following error:-

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @CMKanode nice psychic debugging.

Comment: @ConradFrix Thanks.  Now only if I were as good at figuring out my spouse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lblFName.Text = Session["lblFName"] != null ? Session["lblFName"].ToString();  
lblLName.Text = Session["lblLName"] != null ? Session["lblLName"].ToString();
```